# How can I scroll a container element along with scrollspy?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have many sections with a scrollbar open where the buttons are displayed by the scrollspy. Everything works perfectly with the only difference that if you scroll too far down the scrollspy disappears to the right because it extends off the page. How could I make it so that the scrollbar moves in the direction of the active scrollspy button (the active button in the scrollspy gets a class `active` which is added automatically)?

I am not using jQuery.

Here is the code:

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
  window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0].scrollLeft = 0;
        var menus = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link');
        for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
            if (menus[i].classList.contains('active')) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0].scrollLeft = menus[i].offsetLeft;
            }
        }
    }
}, 1);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ePizza Test Shop</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=0">
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <style>
        body {
            position: relative;
            max-width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        nav {
            position: fixed !important;
            top: 0%;
            overflow: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
            flex-direction: row;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 500px;
        }
        .nav {
            flex-wrap: unset;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="navbar-example2" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light px-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading1">First</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading2">Second</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading3">Third</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading4">Fourth</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading5">Fifth</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading6">First</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading7">Second</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading8">Third</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading9">Fourth</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading10">Fifth</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-example2" data-bs-offset="0" class="scrollspy-example" tabindex="0">
        <h4 id="scrollspyHeading1">First heading</h4>
        <p>First heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Second heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Third heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fourth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fifth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
        <h4 id="scrollspyHeading2">Second heading</h4>
        <p>First heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Second heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Third heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fourth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fifth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
        <h4 id="scrollspyHeading3">Third heading</h4>
        <p>First heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Second heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Third heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fourth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fifth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
        <h4 id="scrollspyHeading4">Fourth heading</h4>
        <p>First heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Second heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Third heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fourth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fifth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
        <h4 id="scrollspyHeading5">Fifth heading</h4>
        <p>First heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Second heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Third heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fourth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fifth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
            <h4 id="scrollspyHeading6" >First heading</h4>
        <p>First heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Second heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Third heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fourth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fifth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
        <h4 id="scrollspyHeading7">Second heading</h4>
        <p>First heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Second heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Third heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fourth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fifth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
        <h4 id="scrollspyHeading8">Third heading</h4>
        <p>First heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Second heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Third heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fourth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fifth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
        <h4 id="scrollspyHeading9">Fourth heading</h4>
        <p>First heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Second heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Third heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fourth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fifth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
        <h4 id="scrollspyHeading10">Fifth heading</h4>
        <p>First heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Second heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Third heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fourth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
            
            Fifth heading
            This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
      </div>
      <script>
        var scrollSpy = new bootstrap.ScrollSpy(document.body, {
            target: '#navbar-example'
        })
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: You'll probably want to apply a callback function to one of the [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/scrollspy/#events) offered by the plugin.

Comment: Good start. Now think through your logic. Will a load event fire repeatedly? No. Therefore it won't do to look for it at intervals.

Comment: @isherwood I thought that because you do it more often when you scroll back and forth that you repeat it. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: The window only loads once. You aren't going to see that event fired a second time. Also, your interval function adds a new load event handler each time, which is inefficient and unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a scroll event listener with a function which will make the navbar to scroll to the active scrollspy button. I've also add `scroll-behavior: smooth` to your navbar CSS in order to avoid that "sudden scrolling".

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');
const h = document.documentElement;

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  nav.scrollTo(nav.querySelector('.active').offsetLeft, 0);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ePizza Test Shop</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=0">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    nav {
      position: fixed !important;
      top: 0%;
      overflow: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      flex-direction: row;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    
    .nav {
      flex-wrap: unset;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="navbar-example2" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light px-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading1">First</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading2">Second</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading3">Third</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading4">Fourth</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading5">Fifth</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading6">First</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading7">Second</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading8">Third</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading9">Fourth</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading10">Fifth</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div data-bs-offset="0" class="scrollspy-example" tabindex="0">
    <h4 id="scrollspyHeading1">First heading</h4>
    <p>First heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here
      to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Second heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example.
      We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Third heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted.
      It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fourth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
      the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fifth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy
      page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
    <h4 id="scrollspyHeading2">Second heading</h4>
    <p>First heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here
      to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Second heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example.
      We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Third heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted.
      It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fourth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
      the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fifth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy
      page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
    <h4 id="scrollspyHeading3">Third heading</h4>
    <p>First heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here
      to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Second heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example.
      We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Third heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted.
      It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fourth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
      the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fifth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy
      page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
    <h4 id="scrollspyHeading4">Fourth heading</h4>
    <p>First heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here
      to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Second heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example.
      We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Third heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted.
      It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fourth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
      the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fifth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy
      page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
    <h4 id="scrollspyHeading5">Fifth heading</h4>
    <p>First heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here
      to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Second heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example.
      We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Third heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted.
      It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fourth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
      the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fifth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy
      page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
    <h4 id="scrollspyHeading6">First heading</h4>
    <p>First heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here
      to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Second heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example.
      We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Third heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted.
      It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fourth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
      the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fifth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy
      page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
    <h4 id="scrollspyHeading7">Second heading</h4>
    <p>First heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here
      to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Second heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example.
      We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Third heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted.
      It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fourth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
      the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fifth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy
      page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
    <h4 id="scrollspyHeading8">Third heading</h4>
    <p>First heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here
      to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Second heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example.
      We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Third heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted.
      It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fourth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
      the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fifth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy
      page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
    <h4 id="scrollspyHeading9">Fourth heading</h4>
    <p>First heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here
      to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Second heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example.
      We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Third heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted.
      It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fourth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
      the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fifth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy
      page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
    <h4 id="scrollspyHeading10">Fifth heading</h4>
    <p>First heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here
      to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Second heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example.
      We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Third heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted.
      It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fourth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
      the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting. Fifth heading This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy
      page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    var scrollSpy = new bootstrap.ScrollSpy(document.body, {
      target: '#navbar-example'
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This looks great, but there's something odd about the demo. It jumps to the last scrollspy item right away, then comes back.

Comment: Thank you so much! But do you know how to fix it that it doesn't jump to the last item?

Comment: It looks like that was happening because you were activating the scrollspy via JavaScript but were also adding the `data-bs-spy` and  `data-bs-target ` attributes to your `.scrollspy-example` container. I've removed those attributes and it's working as expected now.

Comment: Hi @BSdoukos. I just realized that unfortunately this doesn't work in Chrome. How can we fix that?